# How is どこぞの is being used in this sentence?

Tags: particle-の, sentence, adverbs

[image]

I understand どこぞ is "Someplace/somewhere" and a の adjective, but how it's actually modifying 力自慢?

Answer (score 2):

The particle の here indicates the location (e.g. 大阪の友人 "the friend (who is located/ who lives) in Osaka,") so the literal meaning is "力自慢 who is located/ lives somewhere". どこぞ has a vaguer nuance than どこか, so it can be simply translated as "the (said) 力自慢", if context allows.

Comment: +1. Just to be clear, this type of どこぞの adds a nuance like *a certain someone* or *you-know-who*.

Comment: Wait 力自慢 is being modified though? Like "The boasting of one strength from somewhere"?

Is it the actor of the passive? And not adverbial?

Comment: In this sentence, 力自慢 is not an action of boasting one's power, but the person doing so (or strong enough to do so).

Comment: Oh, this is yet another example where [jisho.org is useless](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%8A%9B%E8%87%AA%E6%85%A2)... Here 力自慢 is a noun meaning "(braggart) strongman". All in all, どこぞの力自慢 is "a certain strongman (from somewhere)".